# I don't want my "player" to leave the screen, how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, keydown

This is my JavaScript. Near the bottom you will see an addEventListener, for the keydown event. In that function, the keydown code is there. That code is wrapped in an if function, what goes in the if function, to stop the player from leaving the canvas.

```
function initCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var cW = ctx.canvas.width;
    var cH = ctx.canvas.height;
    var dist = 10;

    function Player() {
        this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = 50, this.h = 50;

        this.render = function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }

    var player = new Player();
    player.x = 100;
    player.y = 225;

    function animate() {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        player.render();
     }
    var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 30);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        if (//I don't know what should go here) {
            if (key_press == "W") {
                player.y -= dist;
            } else if (key_press == "S") {
                player.y += dist;
            } else if (key_press == "A") {
                player.x -= dist;
            } else if (key_press == "D") {
                player.x += dist;
            }
        }
    });

}

window.onload = initCanvas();
```

Comment: Explicitly check that he is not at the edge of the screen (neither on a distance < dist from the edge) ?

Comment: Just check of player.x is out of the map *before* rendering it. If answer is true, give it the max x coordinate.

Comment: I don't get how to do that. Sorry!

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (//I don't know what should go here) {
        if (key_press == "W" && player.y >= dist) {
            player.y -= dist;
        } else if (key_press == "S" && player.y <= (cH - dist)) {
            player.y += dist;
        } else if (key_press == "A" && player.x >= dist) {
            player.x -= dist;
        } else if (key_press == "D" && player.x < (cW - dist)) {
            player.x += dist;
        }
    }
});
```

The extra checks will check that he is not at the edge of the canvas neither at a distance `< dist` from the edge. **Assuming the upper left corner is (0,0).**

Note that it would be nicer to move the user to the edge of the canvas when he is at a distance `< dist` from it. I'll leave this up to you.